# Where is the location or file for Shiny application metrics

Tags: r, shiny, configuration, metrics, shiny-server

If you run a shiny-server, you are able to dive into the metrics (connections count, cpu usage, etc.) via the admin panel. I think this kind of information is collected via the rsconnect::showMetrics API. (Source: https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/metrics.html#ApplicationMetrics)

Where is these data stored? In the sourcecode of the rsconnect package it looks like reading the application logs from shiny server API (https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/blob/fd9bf85027c793fccddf47225c80112e9b796250/R/client-shinyapps.R):

```
    getApplicationMetrics = function(applicationId, series, metrics, from = NULL, until = NULL, interval = NULL) {
  path <- paste("/applications/", applicationId, "/metrics/", series, "/", sep = "")
  query <- list()
  m <- paste(lapply(metrics, function(x) { paste("metric", urlEncode(x), sep = "=") }), collapse = "&")
  if (!is.null(from))
    query$from <- from
  if (!is.null(until))
    query$until <- until
  if (!is.null(interval))
    query$interval <- interval
  GET(service, authInfo, path, paste(m, queryString(query), sep = "&"))
},
```

Where is the corresponding log file located? My shiny application logs in /var/log/shiny-server/ does not contain these kind of information.